# Multilingual Application Toolkit gives no translations

Tags: translation, visual-studio-2022, multilingual-app-toolkit

We've used Multilingual Application Toolkit (MAT) for years in Visual Studio Pro (VS Pro).  For the last half-year at least MAT Version 4 appears to run in VS Pro 2022 Version 17.7.3 *but generates NO new translations.*

MAT leaves old translations alone but no new translations despite appearing to translate text.  Our Azure translation endpoint is working just fine if we connect to it with a test application and request translations.

Anyone else seen this problem?  Perhaps you have a solution or at least a suggestion?  Thank you!

Comment: @Cameron, is this a MAT problem?  Or a user using MAT wrong problem?  Thank you :-)